# Using CAShapeLayer and removeFromSuperLayer

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am making an app, which should draw object from touch points.

I am using `CAShapeLayer`and `UIBezierPath`, but when I use `removeFromSuperlayer()` nothing happens.

I need to delete old shapes and draw just the new one.

I do not know why, but after one build and upload this app to my iPad, Xcode give me an error:

> Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type `CAShapeLayer`

Anyone who can help me?

And another question is:

How to draw just one line?

When I have 2 points, it draws nothing, the app draws just object after 3 points and more.

Here is a part of my code:

```
private func drawObj(){

    let objectPath = UIBezierPath()

    objectPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX[0], y: pointsY[0]))

    let xx = pointsX.count - 1
    print(xx)

    for i in 1...xx {
        objectPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX[i], y: pointsY[i]))
    }

    objectPath.close()

    let object = CAShapeLayer()
    object.removeFromSuperlayer()
    object.path = objectPath.cgPath
    object.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    object.opacity = 0.2
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(object)
}
```

Comment: Re "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type CAShapeLayer" ... We can't answer that question unless you show us what line you are doing this optional chaining on. But there's no optional chaining here...

Comment: @Rob I do not know why, but it appears and then disappears, I think, that that was just a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new `CAShapeLayer`, there's no point in calling `removeFromSuperlayer` on that layer. You only do that for layers that have previously been added as sublayer of some other layer. So, don't call `removeFromSuperlayer` using this new layer that you just created, but save a reference to the previous one. That's the one that you should remove.

Or, as Dmitry pointed out, you should just add the shape layer once, and just update its path:

```
private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.opacity = 0.2
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    return shapeLayer
}()

// add this to your view's layer in the logical place, e.g. `viewDidLoad` 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

// now your draw method only needs to update the path

private func drawObj() {
    let objectPath = UIBezierPath()

    objectPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX[0], y: pointsY[0]))

    for i in 1 ..< pointsX.count {
        objectPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX[i], y: pointsY[i]))
    }

    objectPath.close()

    shapeLayer.path = object.cgPath
}
```

Note, I've also updated the `lineWidth` and the `strokeColor` of the shape layer so that if there are only two points and there is nothing to "fill", you can at least see the stroked path.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, I tried that previousLayer and it works fine. But when i remove close(), it is still the same, not line. Should I set up the width of that line?

Comment: Yes, set the line width and set the stroke color, too.

Comment: By the way, I agree with Dmitry, that you should add the shape layer only once and that your `drawObj` should just update the `path` of that shape layer. That's a more efficient approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for this amazing help

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove the old CAShapeLayer from the parent layer and inserting a new one. Just create one CAShapeLayer, insert it to the parent layer. And then just update the 'path' parameter of it when you need to change it.